# LSF (bsub) exit code inconsistent in airflow SSHOperator

Tags: airflow, exit-code, lsf

## TL;DR

```bash
bsub -K exit 1 || echo Result : $?
```

Results

- `Result : 1` in interactive shell
- `Result : 0` using Airflow SSHOperator

## More details

When I run the following command in an interactive shell, I get the expected output:

```bash
bsub -K exit 1 || echo Result : $?
```

```
Job <3567228> is submitted to default queue <batch_a100>.
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
<<Starting on my_cluster>>
<<Job is finished>>
Result : 1
```

If I do the same using airflow's SSHOperator

```py
run_command = SSHOperator(
    task_id="run_command",
    ssh_conn_id="my_cluster",
    command="bsub -K exit 1 || echo Result : $?",
    dag=dag,
)

run_command
```

I get the following:

```
[2023-07-14, 08:08:16 UTC] {ssh.py:469} INFO - Running command: bsub -K exit 1 || echo Result : $?
[2023-07-14, 08:08:16 UTC] {ssh.py:501} INFO - Job <3567227> is submitted to default queue <batch_a100>.
[2023-07-14, 08:08:16 UTC] {ssh.py:505} WARNING - <<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
[2023-07-14, 08:08:17 UTC] {ssh.py:505} WARNING - <<Starting on my_cluster>>
[2023-07-14, 08:08:21 UTC] {ssh.py:505} WARNING - <<Job is finished>>
[2023-07-14, 08:08:21 UTC] {ssh.py:501} INFO - Result : 0
```

I have verified, that both shells are `bash` using `echo $SHELL`.

I would have expected the same result for both ways, and I think the correct result is `1`.

Where does this difference come from and how can I get the right exit status using Airflow?